# can't delete IOS Builds from my apple developer account before preparing for submitting

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to prepare my app for submitting to App Store.

I created many builds : 4 builds for TestFlight and now i want just to publish my app with the 1.0 version .

I generated certificats for prod and Xcode is linked to my App Developer .

My problem is i get an error message that i already have a version 1,
 so i tried to delete all build in Activity section :

[image: Activity section in my app developer account]

I can't delete or clean history, and i can't publish my app with version 1 .

[image: Xcode Distribute App]

If i submit for Review i got a message :

[image: Newer Build Available]

Comment: It is just warning you that there is a newer build. If you want to submit the currently selected build, click submit. If you don't, click cancel, remove the currently selected NyQuils and select a different build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to remove anything. You need to up the number and submit the new build. Your numbers (TestFlight and AppStore) together can go up only, never down.

Comment: For example try version 1 build 5? But you might have to call it 1.1 build 5, not sure.

Comment: I edited my question, when i submit for review i got this message :

Answer (score 1):

All i have to do is to choose a build when submitting :
  [image]